# how to have a sequence of unique id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

I have already asked this but did not get what I am looking for, I have many tables with column `id` set to auto-increment and primary key.

Table1

id, title, condition...

Table2

id, title, condition...

And I have a search box where I search for products and my query is like

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from table1 where title Like ? or id = ? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $searchterm, $searchterm");
 $stmt->execute();

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from table2 where title Like ? or id = ? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $searchterm, $searchterm");
 $stmt->execute();
```

So if I search for "1" then I will get all the products with id or title 1 but what I want is to have a unique identfier for each row. How can I accomplish this? As I am working with products, there should be a unique id for each product.

Or could it be possible to have a alphabet in front of the id, something like T1, T2, T3?

Comment: This is what MySQL autoincrement columns are for: the autoincrement column is your unique id. Depending on the database engine you're using, you could also create a composite primary key including an autoincrement column with a prefix

Comment: @MarkBaker Okay but there will be id 1 in every tables and when I search for 1 then it will return as many as the number of products. how can I add a prefix?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Since you have set id as a primary key. It will be unique. And your request show only one table at once so I don't see why you would have duplicates results

Comment: @Lmxc . . . Your an improve your question to make it more answerable.  You mention "product", but it is not included as a column in the tables.  You show two tables (with the same structure), but your sample query only mentions one.  You should provide sample data and expected results for a particular query.

Comment: @Masadow I have the same query for every table that I have.

Comment: `"select *, id as id_table1 from table1 where title Like ? or id_table1 = ? "` and so on for every table

Comment: @GordonLinoff When I mentioned "product" I was just referring to the stuff that you buy, I have included the other query for the second table

Comment: It looks like you want the ids to be unique not just within each table, but across all your tables.  Correct?

Comment: @OllieJones that is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using the Oracle table server, you'd use a database entity called a `SEQUENCE` to get a data-base-wide unique id value for your tables.

It's easy enough to emulate `SEQUENCE` entities in MySQL, though, even if it's a little clunky and not quite as space-efficient.

First, create yourself a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (
  sequence_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_id`)
)
```

Then, create your other tables, the ones which will use these unique `sequence_id` values. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE gadget (
  sequence_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  gname VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  gvalue VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sequence_id)
)
```

Here's another:

```
CREATE TABLE widget (
  sequence_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  wname VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  wvalue VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sequence_id)
)
```

Then, *whenever* you insert a row into your other tables, do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES() ;
INSERT INTO widget (sequence_id, wname, wvalue) 
            VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'whatever', 'you_want');
```

or, for the other example table,

```
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES() ;
INSERT INTO gadget (sequence_id, gname, gvalue) 
            VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'another', 'gadget');
```

The trick is this: when you insert each (seemingly empty) row into the `sequence` table it updates the auto-increment sequence_id field. Then, when you use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function it retrieves the most-recently inserted value of that sequence_id.

Be very careful to keep your two `INSERT INTO` statements consecutive, or this will stop working properly.

This works even if many different clients of the database server are doing the inserts, for two reasons;

1. auto-increment is thread-safe. No two sequence numbers can be the same.
2. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` values are maintained one for each distinct connection to the MySQL database.  Different programs (or different threads in a multi-threaded web application) each have their own connections, so they each have their own values of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

By the way, I used `bigint` data for the sequence, but  `int` will work just as well.